# django with celery: how to set up periodic tasks with admin interface

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I have a problem wit setting up periodic tasks with celery.
I got the scheduler running by:

```
celery -A myproject beat -l info --scheduler 
django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

It seems as if the scheduler is up and running my task:
[image]

In the admin interface, I can see/edit the task:
[image]

But it does nothing. IMHO, the file myproject.backend.tasks.importnewvideo.py should be executed.
But it is not.
In the celery manual, I could not find any further information how to set up a task with the admin interface.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You config seems good. Presumably your workers are up and running? They would be responsible for executing the task kicked off by the scheduler.

Comment: You´re right. I forgot to start the workers in the right way.